# Trying to convert .dae file to .gtlf file so I can use with cesium 3d model

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, cesiumjs, gltf

I am trying to convert a 3d dae file to a glTF file. 
I originally built something in SketchUp and exported to .dae.
I tried the following site which is supposed to convert to .gtlf but it converts to a .glb. What is the difference between a .gtlf file and a .glb?
Can I use a .glb to load into Cesium?
Can I just use like an ordinary icon?

https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html

Comment: You can un-check the checkbox that says "Output binary glTF" to obtain a "standard" glTF file. The geometry- and texture data will then be embedded into the JSON using data URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.glb` file extension indicates the file uses the [Binary glTF extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/extensions/Khronos/KHR_binary_glTF), which is an official Khronos extension (hence the KHR prefix) and is fully supported by Ceisum.  Cesium actually ships with some [example .glb files](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/master/Apps/SampleData/models).

The main difference between binary glTF and stock glTF is the binary one is compressed and takes less network bandwidth.

Comment: can I still use the Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
    url : '../../SampleData/models/CesiumGround/Cesium_Ground.gltf',

Comment: Yes, just use it with the .glb extension, and make sure your web server allows serving files with that extension.  It should work fine.